# Making pause in a diagram

Tags: beamer, diagrams

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
  \[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
 \mathcal{H} \arrow[d,"W_A" swap] \arrow[r,"T"]& \mathcal{H} \arrow[d,"W_A"] \\
\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2}) \arrow[r,"\widetilde{T}" swap] & \mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

I want in the first time to show `?` in the place of `$W_A$` and after pressing enter `$W_A$` will appear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to let you know that there is a clear motivation behind the `overlay-beamer-styles` library: it allows you to prevent jumps, which in general happen if you use `\only`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution for the left one. It can be done in the same way for the right one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{frametitle}{subtitle}%
\[
\begin{tikzcd}%[sep=huge]
 \mathcal{H} \only<1>{\arrow[d,"?" swap]}\only<2->{\arrow[d,"W_A" swap]} \arrow[r,"T"]& \mathcal{H} 
 \arrow[d,"W_A"] \\
\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2}) \arrow[r,"\widetilde{T}"] & \mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I would use `overlay-beamer-styles` for that.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{A commutative diagram}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
 \mathcal{H} \arrow[d,"?"{swap,visible on=<1>},"W_A" {swap,visible on=<2>}] 
 \arrow[r,"T"]& \mathcal{H} \arrow[d,"?"{visible on=<1>},"W_A" {visible on=<2>}]  \\
\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2}) \arrow[r,"\widetilde{T}" swap] & \mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `overlay-beamer-styles` library has several advantages, one of them being that it avoids jumps. To see this consider an example with `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{A commutative diagram}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
 \mathcal{H} \arrow[d,"W_A" swap] 
 \only<1>{\arrow[r]}
 \only<2->{\arrow[r,"T"]}& \mathcal{H}
 \arrow[d,"W_A"]  \\
\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2}) \arrow[r,"\widetilde{T}" swap] & \mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, the analogous construction with `overlay-beamer-styles` does not jump.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{A commutative diagram}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
 \mathcal{H} \arrow[d,"W_A" swap] 
 \arrow[r,"T" {visible on=<2->}]& \mathcal{H}
 \arrow[d,"W_A"]  \\
\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2}) \arrow[r,"\widetilde{T}" swap] & \mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It it true that in the special case of your example this is not an issue, but in general it is.

Comment: Can anyone give "making pause" version for this plain TikZ picture in beamer? `\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
(0,0)     node (L1) {$\mathcal{H}$}
+(0:4)    node (R1) {$\mathcal{H}$}
++(-90:2) node (L2) {$\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})$}
+(0:4)    node (R2) {$\mathbf{R}(A^{1/2})$};
\draw[->] (L1)--(R1) node[midway,above]{$T$};
\draw[->] (L2)--(R2) node[midway,below]{$\widetilde{T}$};
\draw[->] (L1)--(L2) node[midway,left,red]{?};\pause
\draw[->] (R1)--(R2) node[midway,right,red]{?};\pause
\end{tikzpicture}
`